# about \usepackage{graphicx,floatrow} in latex

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, captions, floatrow

When I use the code: `\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow}`, the caption of a table ends up under the table. This does not meet the requirement of Springer (book publisher).

Comment: Do you have a reference to their requirements, to see exactly what it is you need?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

`graphicx` has no connection with caption positioning but according to the `floatrow` documentation you should be able to go

```
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
```

to insert captions above the table

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{position=top}%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
foo
\caption{foo}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Does Springer accept the package floatrow? If not then use it the other way round

```
\begin{table}
\caption{foo}
foo
\end{table}
```

Comment: If `floatrow` is banned, might be worth asking them about `caption` and using it's 'move to the top' functionality.